# Replace & with &amp;

Tags: functions

I have a plugin that unfortunately I have no control over, the problem I am experiencing is that it doesn't use `&amp;` in place of `&` and so breaks the sites validation.

Is there a function I can use in my functions.php which will replace all instances of `&` with `&amp;`?

After some investigation inside the plugin I have found the following snippet which is generating the invalid code....

```
    static function GetPermalink($incomingLink = null) {
        $blogUrl = get_bloginfo("url");
        $urlSlug = dsSearchAgent_Rewrite::GetUrlSlug();
        $canonicalUri = self::$CanonicalUri;

        if (isset($canonicalUri) && (!$incomingLink ||     preg_match("/dsidxpress-data/", $incomingLink)))
            return "{$blogUrl}/{$urlSlug}{$canonicalUri}";
        else
            return $incomingLink;
    }
```

It is the $canonicalURi variable that is holding the invalid link, am I right in thinking I need to apply the esc_attr to this variable?

Comment: you've to filter [esc_attr()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr) function. let me know where you don't want `&amp;` to appear.

Comment: Basically its a plugin that pulls in all of the post data from an external source.  I have no way of controlling it.  I was thinking maybe I would have to somehow scan through the page and dynamically replace them one by one?

Comment: give link to plugin.

Comment: I have updated the original question with the snippet of code from the plugin

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the function returning an url, And is always good practice to use [`esc_url();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) wordpress function to escape all characters including the - `&` into `&amp;` before displaying.

*Example usage -*

```
return esc_url( $incomingLink );
```